# Pyomo: Unable to handle quadratic expressions, Language Matching Constraint in Nurse Patient Assignment Model

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, pyomo

I am writing a nurse patient matching algorithm, and I want to incorporate something into the objective function that encourages a language match between nurses and patients. The goal is to assign each patient to exactly one nurse while minimizing uneven workload distribution, distance between rooms, continuity of care, language matching, etc. I've shown just the language match element for simplicity.

#### Sets

```
model.PatientIDs  = {0, 1, 2}
model.NurseIDs = {a, b}
```

#### Patient Language - Indexed parameter (indexed by patient)

```
model.PATIENT_LANGUAGE = {(0: English), (1: Spanish), (2: English)}
```

#### Nurse Language - Indexed parameter (indexed by nurse)

```
model.NURSE_LANGUAGE = {(a: English), (b: Spanish)}
```

#### Indexed parameter (indexed by patient, nurse) - tracks whether nurse language matches patient language, pre-computed from patient language and nurse language

```
model.LANGUAGES_MATCH = {(0, a): 1, (0, b): 0, (1, a) : 0, (1, b) : 1, (2, a) : 1, (2, b) : 0}
```

#### Decision variable (indexed by (patient, nurse))

```
model.ASSIGNMENTS = {(0, a): 0, (0, b): 1, (1, a) : 1, (1, b) : 1, (2, a) : 0, (2, b) : 0}
```

#### Dummy decision variable (indexed by (patient, nurse))

```
model.DUMMY_LANGUAGE = {(0, a): 1, (0, b): 0, (1, a) : 0, (1, b) : 1, (2, a) : 1, (2, b) : 0}
```

This is the constraint I constructed:

```
def matches_language(self, patient, nurse): # LANGUAGE
    return model.LANGUAGE_DUMMY[patient, nurse] <= model.ASSIGNMENTS[patient, nurse] * model.LANGUAGE_MATCH[patient, nurse]

model.LANG_MATCH = pe.Constraint(model.P, model.N, rule = matches_language)
```

Thus, ASSIGNMENTS(p1, n1) acts as a selector for whether we need to care about p1 and n1 having matching languages. I maximize lang_match in my objective function, which in turn should maximize the RHS of the constraint as well, promoting assignments for which languages match.  However, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Solver unable to handle quadratic expressions. Constraint at issue: 'LANG_MATCH[1]'
```

I didn't think this would be quadratic since model.LANGUAGES_MATCH is a parameter (filled with scalars), not a variable. Can someone help me understand why this error is being thrown/suggest a way to fix it?

Comment: Could you post more of your model implementation? In particular how are you declaring the variables and parameters because all you're showing above is Python dictionaries not Pyomo components.

Comment: The variables and parameters are in fact the Pyomo elements I am using - I just wrote them as Python dictionaries for easy interpretation. You can imagine that those dictionaries are wrapped in pe.Param(initialize = <item>) or pe.Set(initialize = <item>)  or pe.Var(initialize = <item>) . I've written a minimal reproducible example since I'm asking about how to express this constraint in particular and didn't want to overcomplicate with unnecessary information (if I post the whole model it'll be too much to read).

Comment: Can you provide a runnable MRE? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't real clear from your mixing of pseudocode and code what is going on here.  But if you have already computed some "bonus points" for matching patient `p` with nurse `n` and covered all the combos.  (Aside:  You can be as creative as you want here to make this lookup table...  but that is separate from `pyomo`)

So, you have this table of bonus points like: `{(n1, p1): 0, (n1, p2): 5, ...}`

And you have a decision variable `x[n, p]` then you do not need any constraints or dummy variables, just make it a component of the objective function.

```
obj = <some other stuff> + w * sum(m.x[n, p] * m.language_bonus[n, p] for n in N for p in P)
```

where `w` is some likely needed fractional weight of this score relative to the rest of the stuff.

You are probably getting "quadratic" warnings because you are multiplying variables together, which is not necessary.